# How to make a ImageView appear at a random position within a circle?

Tags: java, android, position, android-imageview, cornerradius

I have a layout that looks something like this

[image]

Above is a setup which contains a Frame layout which contains a View and an Image View inside of it. The View contains a drawing which is a circle.

I will have the access to the value/size of the radius of the circle at runtime.

I am trying to show an Image using an ImageView inside that circle, but I do not want the Image to cross the circle. I will change the position of the ImageView every second.

**Can anyone help me to achieve the logic on how to place the Image inside the circle so that it does not cross that.**

Comment: Seems like simple math (with assumption that center of the circle is (0,0) then all x^2 + y^2 should be less than r^2 obviously it is enough to check only vertices of image view) ... what had you tried so far?

Comment: @Selvin Thanks for the reply. Frankly I have no clue to this problem. Hence I have not been able to figure out what to try. Can you please help.

Comment: I guess it's basic trigonometry. Moreover, I'd suggest that the "circle" is actually a *hole*  in the surrounding square frame and the ImageView floats **underneath** it. This way, the eventual mismatching corner(s) would be covered by the visible portion of the frame.

Comment: @Selvin Thanks for the help. Working more on your solution helped me to solve the problem. Can you please post an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Selvin I solved the issue.

This is how I solved it

```
int x=XPOSITION;
int y=YPOSITION;
int r=RADIUS;
int r2=0;
int xy2=0;
```

Now this is how I am check if the point is inside the circle or not.

```
  Formula = r^2>(x^2+y^2)
    r2=r*r;
    xy2=(x*x)+(y*y);

    if(r2>xy2)
    {
      Point is inside the circle
    }
```